# How to override a function using another plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin which has a function lets say function1 in class named class1. Now I want to override this function from another plugin such that when I activate the another plugin then the override function should work instead of the function present in the first plugin. How can I do that?
I have tried extending that class which has function1 into the another plugin but don't know how to override it and make function2 work instead of function1.

Comment: if the plugin is designed well , it should be using hooks/filters to insert code, you can unhook the function and replace with your own. If not, there is little you can do, you can't have two functions with the same name in php, so you would need to modify the plugin itself.

Comment: I can not find any hooks/filters and i don't want to change the source code either.

Comment: not much you can do so, but there will nearly always be a hook/filter somewhere in the process, you might have to go up a few functions in the process thats running.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to do same as wordpress pluggable functions.

Whatever function you want to override create a function with that name and give high priority. So always the new function will execute.

Comment: How can i give second function high priority?

Comment: Pluggable functions only let you override certain core functions, not plugin functions

Comment: what can I do at this moment?